# Could you please tell me resistor parallel with piezo PKLCS1212E4001-R1

Tags: transistors, resistors, pwm, piezo

[image]Please could you tell me the reason why you add a resistor in parallel with a piezo?[image]

Comment: What piezo? There’s more than one type of ‘piezo’

Comment: Hi Kartman. This is the link to the piezo https://www.murata.com/en-eu/products/productdetail?partno=PKLCS1212E4001-R1

Answer (score 1):

The piezo speaker is mainly capacitive device.

It means it holds a charge and it must be discharged.

The transistor is only able to charge the capacitance when the transistor is turned on.

When the transistor is turned off, it cannot discharge the capacitance.

The resistor is needed to discharge the capacitance when the transistor is turned off.